# Credit card repayment calculator

Tags: python, python-3.x

Good morning, It's been a long time since I've played around with python and I seem to have forgotten a fair bit.

I'm trying to make a repayment credit card repayment calculator, I've got it to work but I'm trying to improve it. currently It works if I fill in a payment amount and that will tell me how long it will take to pay, However I would like to fill in number of payments instead and then it tell me how much I need to pay. This is my code, can someone please point me in the right direction

```
original_amount = amount = 500
repayment = 1
interest = 30.34

total_interest = 0
number_of_payments = 8


def calculate_interest(old_balance):
    global interest
    global monthly_interest
    global total_interest
    monthly_interest_percent = interest / 100 / 12
    monthly_interest = old_balance * monthly_interest_percent
    new_balance = old_balance + monthly_interest
    total_interest += monthly_interest
    return new_balance


count = 0


while amount > 0:
    card_value = calculate_interest(amount)
    amount = card_value - repayment
    count += 1

    if count > number_of_payments:
        repayment += 1
```

Comment: @CherryDT I've run this multiple times with different figures and I am happy my maths is correct, I believe this is a coding issue and the problem lies within the placement of the if statement within the while loop

Comment: Sorry - Ok then I misunderstood the question, I thought this existing code is for filling in payment amount and you want to change it to fill in number of payments and don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is this:

```
if count > number_of_payments:
    repayment += 1
```

repayment is the amount you are repaying but I don't think that's what you want to increment here, you probably want to increment the number_of_payments.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I have found the solution now. It worked once I reset the values back to zero within the for loop